# Flutter : background is squeezed to the left when keyboard shows up

Tags: flutter, keyboard, resize, scaffold

I have a problem when I want to fill a TextView and the keyboard shows up, the scaffold is squeezing to the left.

Anybody have a clue about that ?

This is my code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final authentCubit = context.watch<AuthentificationCubit>();
    final UserRepository user = UserRepository();
    print(user.getUserName());
    return Scaffold(

      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Route'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Deconnexion'),
              onPressed: () {
                authentCubit.signOut();
              },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Formulaire contact'),
              onPressed: () {
                showDialog(context: context,builder: (context)=> ContactForm());
              },
            ),
            TextField(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


}
```

This is a screen of my problem

[image: Capture]

Thank you

Comment: I have tested your code in a real device and it's working clearly. Can you try it on a real device or another emulator?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already answered to the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had two scaffold in my tree, this is why "resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false," wasn't working.